# Android: change accessibility order programmatically

Tags: java, android, accessibility, screen-readers, talkback

Is there a way to change the order that the screen reader, in android case the TalkBack, has to read the accessible elements?
Like if I have 3 elements, initially read in order b1, b2, b3, after I press a certain button the order change and become b3, b1, b2?

**EDIT**
This is what I tried following @Nikos Hidalgo hint

CODE:

```
    Button b1,b2,b3, changeorder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout linearlayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

    changeorder = new Button(this);
    changeorder.setText("Presso to change order");
    changeorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("BUTTON","Clicked change order button");

            changeorder.setAccessibilityTraversalBefore(b3.getId());
            b3.setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(changeorder.getId());
            b3.setAccessibilityTraversalBefore(b1.getId());
            b1.setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(b3.getId());
            b1.setAccessibilityTraversalBefore(b2.getId());
            b2.setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(b1.getId());
            changeorder.setText("Order changed b3,b1,b2");

        }
    });
    changeorder.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
    linearlayout.addView(changeorder);

    b1 = new Button(this);
    b1.setText("BUTTON 1");
    b1.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
    linearlayout.addView(b1);


    b2 = new Button(this);
    b2.setText("BUTTON 2");
    b2.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
    linearlayout.addView(b2);


    b3 = new Button(this);
    b3.setText("BUTTON 3");
    b3.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
    linearlayout.addView(b3);


    }
```

Comment: can you explain why you want the accessibility order different to the order in the DOM or the tab order? Otherwise it is likely you are going to introduce accessibility problems and errors rather than solve them.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Because in applications in which elements can move on the screen, like application that uses drag and drop, after some views moved I need to reorder their accessibility order.

Answer (score 7):

You can programmatically define/change the traversal order (order with which the views are parsed in TalkBalk) using the following methods:

```
public void setAccessibilityTraversalAfter (int afterId)
```

> Sets the id of a view after which this one is visited in accessibility traversal. A screen-reader must visit the content of the other view before the content of this one. For example, if view B is set to be after view A, then a screen-reader will traverse the entire content of A before traversing the entire content of B, regardles [sic] of what traversal strategy it is using.

([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(int)))

```
public void setAccessibilityTraversalBefore (int beforeId)
```

> Sets the id of a view before which this one is visited in accessibility traversal. A screen-reader must visit the content of this view before the content of the one it precedes. For example, if view B is set to be before view A, then a screen-reader will traverse the entire content of B before traversing the entire content of A, regardles [sic] of what traversal strategy it is using.

([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAccessibilityTraversalBefore(int)))

As they’re both public methods of View you could use them like this:

```
findView(R.id.view1).setAccessibilityTraversalBefore(R.id.view2);
```

**EDIT**: 
make sure that all your views are focusable and if you're programmatically adding more views, make sure that you set the `importantForAccessibility` attribute.

e.g. `myView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);`

Comment: I tried that having 3 buttons (b1,b2,b3), and after pressing a 4° button I used `b1.setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(b3.getId());`
`b2.setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(b1.getId());` tho change the order to b3,b1,b2, but nothing happened

Comment: @Poli97 are the buttons dynamically created? I'm wondering whether depending on when and how you bind the views you need to restart the activity. If you could edit your question to add all the relevant code, it'll probably be easier to see what's happening.

Comment: Yes, the buttons are dynamically created. I tried using your suggestion `myView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES)`, but it didn't work either. I edited the question and I added the code that I tried. Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: hey, have you found any solution for that?

Comment: @Poli97 Sorry,  that solution has worked for me in the past. Try calling invalidate() on the views after you've changed the order to force them to redraw and see if that makes a difference.